# How do I slow down the Flume Sequence Generator

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

Flume has a source called a [Sequence Generator](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#sequence-generator-source) that can be used for testing; it just generates random data (incrementing numbers).

I'm using it for testing/debugging but it generates a lot of data very quickly. How can I make it generate less amounts of data per second?

Answer (score 0):

Flume doesn't provide any such configuration as of now.

To reduce the frequency of data you can configure `batchSize` parameter to a higher value

or better way is to write your own flume source like this [SequenceGeneratorSource](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.flume/flume-ng-core/1.1.0-cdh3u4/org/apache/flume/source/SequenceGeneratorSource.java)